# Have one method that will be used in Views, Controllers and Worker in rails app. What is best place to define it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I have a method that will be used in different Views, Controllers and in different Workers as well so what is best place to define this method such that code would not be get repeated.

Comment: It sounds like it should be in a model. That's the only object that can interact directly or otherwise with all of those layers. A helper won't help you in the worker, or the controller, unless you define it in the controller; but then it won't be accessible to the worker. You can also use a concern and mix it where needed. Or Nixon the helper where needed.

Comment: You can define a method in helper too.

Answer (score 0):

In lib directory you can create module and define a method over there so you can access that method anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Best place is `Helper`, define it in `application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def printing
      "Printing..."
  end
end
```

and include it in `ApplicationController`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include ApplicationHelper
end
```